# Fluent validation (can't start)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

My question is about http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com library.
I download .dll's from this link and include in project library **FluentValidation.Mvc.dll**

```
using FluentValidation.Mvc;
class QuestionValidator:AbstractValidator<Question>
{
}
```

But resharper don't suggest me some including variants. It means that I included wrong lbrary or not included some other. If I need to include other library, can you explain what's wrong and give me link to download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to instal this using NuGet. It does everything to work well.

In Visual Studio do this

> Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console

Then enter `Install-Package FluentValidation.MVC3`

OR

> right click on your project > Add Library Package Reference > search for FluentValidation

[image]